# PowerShell Script unmounting All mounted images

Tags: powershell, umount

Just started using PowerShell Script.

I have created scripts for my kids, that Mount a diskimage and then runs the executable for that game.

Is there a way to make a a script to be run at logoff that will dismount all mounted image files?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: It was more in the way to hear if it would be possible to do it?

Comment: If you can mount them you can unmount them. You can run a script at logoff. Search for "windows run script at logoff"

Answer (score 0):

There sure is. The command is `dismount-diskimage`.

Here's the full Technet site for this command: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848693(v=wps.630).aspx

But the basics are that you just need to pass it the path of the image you've mounted that you wish to dismount. You could probably have a script poll for any mounted images and pass the results along to this command.